# Rails booking feature with Payment Gateway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mangopay

novice Rails Back-end developer here. Trying to integrate a payment gateway for the first time. Hopefully I can manage to explain everything fine.

I'm building a booking marketplace platform using the payment gateway `Mangopay` (unnecessary to know this tech for my request)

So, from how I imagined the booking process, I have these 2 models :

`Bookings`

```
# Schema
create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "booking_transaction_id", null: false
  ...
end

# Model
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :booking_transaction
  ...
end
```

`Booking_transactions` (responsible for all the logic between a booking and the payment gateway)

```
# Schema
create_table "booking_transactions", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "booking_id", null: false
  ...
end

# Model
class BookingTransaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :booking
  ...
end
```

I then have a controller where I want to create a `booking`. But a booking needs a `booking_transaction` right ? I started writing something like such in my controller :

```
def create
  booking = current_user.bookings.create!(

  )
end
```

But of course, I get a `NotNullViolation` because creating a booking require to have a `booking_transaction_id`. So I'm not sure what the process should look like.

Thanks in advance for any given help.

Comment: You cannot have two tables requiring each other in this way, why does Booking have to have `booking_transaction_id`?

Comment: Realised that yesterday. Fixed my issue. I'll post a solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I shouldn't have the 2 models requiring each other.

I removed the `booking_transaction` reference (ie `booking_transaction_id`) from the `booking` model.

And can now create a booking like this :

```
def create
  transaction = BookingTransaction.new

  booking = current_user.bookings.create!(
    transaction: transaction
    ...
  )
end
```

This will then create a `booking_transaction` and attach it on the newly created `booking` instance thanks to the Rails Way.